# $U=\{(a,b,c,d)|b-3c+d=0\}$ $W=\{(a,b,c,d)|a=d,b=3c\}$ How can I find $U \cap W$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the subspaces $U=\{(a,b,c,d)|b-3c+d=0\}$ and  $W=\{(a,b,c,d)|a=d,b=3c\}$ How can i find the basis and dimension of $U \cap W$?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at $(a,b,c,d)$ satisfying **all** equations:$$b-3c+d=0\\a=d\\b=3c$$
From the first and third, you get $d=0$. Then you conclude that $a=0$, so in the end, you get $(a,b,c,d)=(0,3c,c,0)$

Comment: i forgot to write in the question, it asks to find the basis and the dimension of their intersection. so (0,3c,c,0) is the basis or of their intersection or?

Comment: The intersection has dimension of $1$, with a possible basis of ${(0,3,1,0)}$. The formal way to say it is like in @ChrisCuster 's answer:  $U\cap W=\operatorname {span}\{(0,3,1,0)\}$

Comment: so the basis is the span{(0,3,1,0)}? thank you :)

Comment: The basis is just one vector, $(0,3,1,0)$. When you say that the intersection is the span of a set of vectors, it means that the intersection is **all** vectors that can be obtained by a linear combination of the basis vectors. In this case, you have only one basis vector, so  $\operatorname {span}\{(0,3,1,0)\}=\{(0,3x,x,0)|x\in\mathbb R\}$

Comment: oh okay so the basis is (0,3,1,0). thank you!!  could i ask and something else? if i have T(x, y) = (5x + y, 3x − 2y) and S = {(1, 2), (2, 3)} and it asks to find the matrix A representing T relative to the basis S, how can i do this?

Comment: @Mary Ask it as a separate question, so one can answer with details.

Comment: could you tell me just a hint?

Comment: $x=u+2v$ and $y=2u+3v$

Comment: should i substitute the coef of u and v to the linear map?

Comment: Yes. But you see that we drifted away from the original problem

Comment: okay,sorry and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The intersection is $U\cap W=\operatorname {span}\{(0,3,1,0)\}$.

Comment: thank you very much!! could i ask and something else? if i have T(x, y) = (5x + y, 3x − 2y) and S = {(1, 2), (2, 3)} Find the matrix A representing T relative to the basis S.

Comment: how could i do this?

Comment: $A=\begin {pmatrix}5&1\\3&-2\end{pmatrix}$ is the matrix rel the standard basis.  Now let $B=\begin {pmatrix}1&2\\2&3\end{pmatrix}$.  Your matrix is $B^{-1}AB$.

Comment: oh,i can not just substitute the (1,2),(2,3) to the linear map?or? i didnt understand it very well

Comment: Actually,  you're right.  That may be easier.   The columns will be $(7,-1)$ and $(13,0)$.

Comment: yes,that's what i found! thank you

Comment: Sorry, if you want the matrix for $T$ rel the new basis, you need to write $(7,-1)$ and $(13,0)$ in terms of that basis.  I get $\begin{pmatrix}-23&-30\\15&26\end {pmatrix}$.

Comment: i want  the matrix A representing T relative to the basis S. so i have to calculate the inverse?

Comment: Yes.  That's what I used.  The inverse of my $B$, the change of basis matrix.

Comment: i did it and i got ((-23,15) ,(-39,26))

Comment: You're right.   Careless mistake.

Comment: okay, thank you so much for the help

Comment: You're welcome.